# Установка PunBB

Tags: веб-программирование, cms

Я залил Punbb на свой сайт (хостинг с высшими php и mysql), подскажите, как узнать данные для установки движка. Адрес сервера Mysql, имя MySql, логин, пароль и др. Адрес проекта -
iamonline.h19.ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вашего же хостера: http://h19.ru/faq.shtml

Вы ж базу сами создаете, и сами указываете для нее логин, пароль и т.п.